# SQL JSON Table Issue

Tags: sql

I am importing data from an external JSON file, which is working properly, but I also wish to include a column which stores the current date / time, to store when the data was extracted.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE main.loadJSON
AS 

DECLARE @Details NVARCHAR(MAX)

SELECT @Details = 
    BulkColumn
    FROM OPENROWSET(BULK'C:\Users\Vally\Desktop\persondata.json',SINGLE_CLOB) JSON



    INSERT INTO main.jsontable (dateloaded,name,surname,email,age,balance,country,registered)
    VALUES(GETDATE(),
    (SELECT *
    FROM OPENJSON(@Details,'$.PersonDetails.Person')        
    WITH(
        [Name] NVARCHAR(50)         '$.first_name',
        [Surname] NVARCHAR(50)      '$.last_name',
        [Email] NVARCHAR(50)        '$.email',
        [Age] NVARCHAR(50)          '$.age',
        [Balance] NVARCHAR(50)      '$.balance',
        [Country] NVARCHAR(50)      '$.country',
        [Registered] NVARCHAR(50)   '$.registered'
        )
    )
)
GO
```

It is giving me 2 errors.

Line 27
Only one expression can be specified in the select list when the subquery is not introduced with EXISTS.

Line 13
There are more columns in the INSERT statement than values specified in the VALUES clause. The number of values in the VALUES clause must match the number of columns specified in the INSERT statement.

What is the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

refrain from using SELECT * 
instead specify all your columns explicitly

Comment: How would I select the JSON statements using SELECT? I tried putting in the $ values but that didn't work, all it did was input the text '$.first_name'..etc

Comment: Nevermind, i've fixed it. If anyone else is having this problem, I simply put [name],[surname] into the select, thank you randy :)